# Usar preg_replace com condição

Tags: php

Eu tenho a seguinte string, que pode ser a representação de um HTML ou XML, não faz diferença:

```
<node1>
    <node2>Conteudo exemplo</node2>
    <node3>Conteudo exemplo</node3>
    <node4>Conteudo exemplo</node4>
    <node5>
        <node6>Conteudo exemplo</node6>
    </node5>
</node1>
```

Preciso criar uma **pattern** para o **preg_replace** conseguir substituir as ocorrências de **>** que não estejam seguidas do carácter **<**, ou seja só será substituído o os caracteres **>** que representam o fechamento de uma tag sem nós filhos no exemplo acima.

Tenho ciência que há formas melhores de manipular documentos com essa estrutura, por exemplo usando a Classe **DOMDocument**, mas nesse caso preciso realmente usar o **preg_replace**.

Simulando um resultado esperado, substituindo o carácter **>** por **@**:

```
<node1>
    <node2@Conteudo exemplo</node2>
    <node3@Conteudo exemplo</node3>
    <node4@Conteudo exemplo</node4>
    <node5>
        <node6@Conteudo exemplo</node6>
    </node5>
</node1>
```

Comment: Tem como colocar o resultado esperado? Para mim não ficou claro o que seria removido da *string* nesse exemplo.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Coloquei uma simulação do resultado esperado.

Comment: Acho que ele quis dizer o seguinte, remover "<" e ">" do conteúdo, sem alterar as tags.

Comment: @WictorChaves Na verdade a questão chave é a implementação de uma condição ao executar o preg_replace. Nesse caso eu preciso substituir os caracteres ">" que não tenham em seguida o carácter "<".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não sei se é a melhor solução, mas tenta fazer assim no PHP:

```
preg_replace('/>(.*?)</', '@$1<', $XML_HTML);
```

Comment: Ótimo, produziu o resultado esperado. Muito obrigado!